# Android Room Student + School (One-to-Many relation) get school name

Tags: android, relationship, android-room

I'm new to Room and I was playing with a sample app that registers Students and shows them in a RecyclerView.

I have a Student class something like:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String studentNumber;
    private String name;
    private int schoolId;
}
```

a School class:

```
@Entity
public class School {
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

With a one-to-many relation ( One school has a list of students and a student belongs to a school)

```
public class SchoolWithStudents {
    @Embedded private School school;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "id",
         entityColumn = "schoolId"
    )
    private List<Student> studentList;
}
```

If I have an Activity where I want to show the Student details including the school name. It seems very odd to me having to query the database only to get the school name something like getSchoolById.

I come from Spring Boot where it's perfectly normal to have a School object embedded in the Student class and still manage the relations.

So getting the school name would be as easy as : student.getSchool.getName().
I'm I seeing this correctly? Do I really need the extra query? I'm not using the SchoolWithStudents for nothing yet, just declared for arquitecture purposes

Answer (score 1):

> It seems very odd to me having to query the database only to get the school name something like getSchoolById

You haven't to do like that. In any case it is enough to make just one call to Room to get all data what you want.

If you make next call:

```
@Query("SELECT * from school")
List<SchoolWithStudents> loadSchoolWithStudents();
```

you'll get list with embedded `School` object, so there is no need for additional query - you have school' name and all its attributes inside your response (not inside `Student` object, but anyway you can get it easily from `School` object with `school.getName()`).

If you want to get list with another structure - `StudentWithSchool` (where both Student and School will be "on the same level"), you can do it with:

```
public class StudentWithSchool {
    @Embedded private Student student;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "schoolId",
         entityColumn = "id"
    )
    private School school;
}
```

and query method:

```
@Query("SELECT * from student")
List<StudentWithSchool> loadStudentWithSchool();
```

Comment: I think implementing that StudentWithSchool might do the trick. Never occurred to me to flip it around as I haven't found many examples of room on the web. Only simple one entity demo projects.

Student is the main entity in the app. The main recyclerview is a list of all students in the student table, and when you click on an item you go to a details screen where you can see the student info and to what school they belong.

Comment: I just can add that if you familiar with Sql you can get equivalent result without `@Relation` - just to add some complexity to your query (use in query "Left Join" with the second table).

Comment: The thing is I was trying to learn the proper way of doing this with Room , relations etc. It seems a very common use case, and using more complex SQL seems to be going out of the Room way.